# nodejs/bower Error "toLowerCase"

Tags: node.js, bash, debian, bower, wysihtml5

I tried an tried, locally and globally, more than 4 times, but I can't figure out how to install (and configure) nodejs/bower/wysihtml5-editor. That is what happend:

I would like to use this fancy wysiwyg-editor: [here](https://github.com/bootstrap-wysiwyg/bootstrap3-wysiwyg#examples)

So I had to do some research because I'm not a pro but I did this:

```
1. sudo apt-get update

2. sudo apt-get install git-core curl build-essential openssl libssl-dev

3. sudo git clone https://www.github.com/joyent/node.git

4. cd node

5. git tag #to see the versions

6. sudo git checkout v0.9.9

7. sudo ./configure

8. sudo make

9. sudo make install

10. sudo curl -L https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh

11. sudo npm -g grunt-cli

12. sudo npm install grunt

13. sudo npm install handlebars -g

14. sudo npm install -g bower

15. bower install bootstrap3-wysihtml5-bower
```

(Here is the [tutorial](https://ariejan.net/2011/10/24/installing-node-js-and-npm-on-ubuntu-debian/))

But at the last Step I got the following Error-message (every god-damn-time):

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'toLowerCase'
at Function.Buffer.isEncoding (buffer.js:240:32)
at assertEncoding (evalmachine.<anonymous>:98:27)
at Object.fs.writeFileSync (evalmachine.<anonymous>:908:3)
at Object.create.all.set (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/index.js:64:8)
at Object.Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/index.js:27:11)
at new Insight (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/lib/index.js:26:34)
at ensureInsight (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/util/analytics.js:26:19)
at Object.setup (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/util/analytics.js:43:9)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower:72:11)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

I referenced to all files the Editor depends on:

```html
<script src="node/node_modules/handlebars/lib/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="node/node_modules/handlebars/lib/handlebars.runtime.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="wysihtml5/dist/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wysihtml5/dist/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="wysihtml5/dist/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css">
```

I used google, stackoverflow, ... but it seems that no one had this problem. I would be so happy if anybody out there would give me an answer.

The System is a Linux XXX 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.60-1+deb7u3 x86_64 GNU/Linux.

Like I said I uninstalled all components (grunt, bower, handlebars, npm/nodejs) a few times an tried it in other directorys and so on; but no success.

I bet its a little fault which "drives me literally crazy and goes me on my sack". Should I install npm an all components only for using the editor? Or is it just fine by reference to the files?

Everything I get in the frontend is a non-styled-broken-editor...

Thanks guys and girls. :)

Comment: `./configure` and `make` do not need (and should not have `sudo` access), just for the record. And neither does the `curl` part of that pipeline. Oh and neither did the `git clone`.

Comment: Should `bower install bootstrap-wysihtml5-bower` be `bower install bootstrap3-wysihtml5-bower`?

Comment: yes. sorry. don't mind the "sudos". ;) and yes, it ist bootstrap3-wysihtml5-bower. I change it.

Comment: You actually ran that with `bootstrap3-...` not `bootstrap-...` when you got the error, correct? (And the `sudo`s matter since they can do bad things and have permissions set wrong for a normal user to use the files/directories they dealt with.)

Comment: Yeah, I used bootstrap3-... I corrected the sudos in the post above. I think it's ok now? But do you know, why this error with bower occur?

Comment: I thought it may be a fault with our Webserver...

Comment: I don't think, but certainly don't know, that `bower install` is interacting with your webserver at all. That seems likely to be a local command to me. Actually, looking at that a bit closer it looks like it could be encoding/locale related. What locale are you running in? What locales are available on your system? Can you find the function(s) that are listed in that traceback and see what they are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aww man. I got it.

I reinstalled all components and bower thows a `WARN engine` while installing. So I updated node to the latest version.

But there was the problem with the shi**y frontend. I just found out that you have to reference a lot of files to get it right.

My node version: `v0.12.0`
My bower version: `v1.3.12`
My npm version: `v2.5.1`
My nodejs version: `v0.10.36`

I don't know whether you need these (I don't think so) to get the editor running.

So here are the files I referenced:

```html
<!-- WYSIHTML5-EDITOR -->
<link href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="bower_components/components-font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/bootstrap3-wysihtml5-bower/dist/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap3-wysihtml5-bower/dist/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.css">
<!-- WYSIHTML5-EDITOR -->

<!-- SCRIPTS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.runtime.min.js"></script>
<!-- SCRIPTS -->
```

Hope this will help somebody.